# Question about stative verbs

Tags: meaning

I really want to know if there is a change in meaning when stative verbs used in a progressive form, particularly in these 5 verbs' meaning:
hate-hating
want-wanting
know-knowing
contain-containing
need-needing
thanks beforehand

Comment: Are you talking about the use of state verbs in the present continuous (e.g. I am needing it) or as gerunds (e.g. wanting it is awful)?

Comment: Yes, like i have been wanting to do it for a long time or I was hating him

Comment: When discussing meaning, context plays a big role. Please include some context in your question.